# Add active class and change css of other items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have this menu

```
            <ul id="menu" class="clearfix">
                <li>
                    <a href="">Product 1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="">Product 2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="">Product 3</a>
                </li>
                <li class="last">
                    <a href="">Product 4</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
```

I want to make this effect. when you enter the page the text color of the menu items are white. If you click on one item it becomes active (keeping the white color text) and all the other items change it's color to gray, also when you hover over one the affected items are all the others.

I have tried with the .addClass but I have only managed to add the active class to the current item, but not change the others that aren´t active after the first click.

Anyone know the best jquery approach to this?

Comment: `when you hover over one the affected items are all the others.` What does this mean?

Comment: the other people got it ;) haha sorry, as you may have guessed english is not my main language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#menu li").hover(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('grey').siblings().addClass('grey');
}, function() {
    $(this).addClass('grey').siblings('.active').removeClass('grey');
    //
}).on('click', function() {
    $(this).removeClass('grey').addClass('active').siblings().addClass('grey').removeClass('active')
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y7Cn5/

Comment: this answer the question completely, it´s perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like this:

### Updated, with hover functionality

## jsFiddle

```
$("#menu > li").on("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(".active").removeClass("active");
    $(this).removeClass("non-active").addClass("active").siblings().addClass("non-active");
})
.hover(function(e) {
    $(".non-hover").removeClass("non-hover");
    $(this).addClass("hover").siblings().addClass("non-hover");
}, function(e) {
    $(".hover, .non-hover").removeClass("hover non-hover");
})
```

and if this doesn't answer the question, then the question is not understood and needs some rewording, this is everything asked about in the question

Comment: This does not answer is his question.

Comment: @Rikoshay yes, it exactly answers the question

Comment: Sure, now after you... Edited it from your 2 line answer

Comment: @Rikoshay the first little answer did answer the question except for the hover, which i was getting too, and you never answered at all

Answer (score 0):

Here you go (siblings) selects all OTHER items in the same node

```
$("#menu li").click(function(){
  $(this).addClass("active").css("color","white")
  $(this).siblings().css("color","gray")
})
```

Comment: this doesn´t work with the hover also :( but it does the active change

Comment: I missed the hover part of your question, my appologies

Comment: Also the second time a li element is clicked the active class is not removed so this makes it possible for two items to potentially have the class active

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("#menu > li").hover( function( ) {
    $(this).removeClass("hovered").siblings().addClass("hovered");
}, function( ) {
    $(this).addClass("hovered");
});

$("#menu > li").click( function( ) {
    $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
});
```